# How to bind additional columns to a List/Dictionary/otherwise collection of data

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

Have a List bound as the itemssource for a grid.  MyObject has properties that are in turn bound as the individual column bindings:

```
        <data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <data:DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{ListOfMyObject}">
                </data:DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FOO" Binding="{Binding Foo}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="BAR" Binding="{Binding Bar}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

The class has properties Foo and Bar that get assigned from another property's data.  This property is a large set of data that is accessible by an indexer (essentially acts as a collection):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Foo;
    public string Bar;

    public MainData Lots;
}
```

I need to be able to dynamically add columns to the grid from MainData, like MainData[217].  I've played around with [this idea](http://www.ditran.net/silverlight-datagrid-dynamic-columns-adding-code-behind-sortabilities) but can't seem to tweak it correctly.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't thinking clearly enough apparently.

Following the premise linked in the orignal post, I've added a separate List of IDs.  Rather than attempting to spin through the source data and add columns, I spin through this list.  These IDs in turn look up other values, e.g. header text, from a data dictionary and pass the ID (which serves as my indexer noted above) to the converter.